# HP Envy 6 Overheating

Tags: ati, overheating, xubuntu, catalyst

I've got some overheating issues with my HP Envy 6 1170sf. When I start my ultrabook, the minimal heat is 76°C if I do nothing. There is nothing to see in powertop, and Jupiter is set to "power saving".
I've tried to install the AMD Catalyst drivers to use the Intel GPU instead of the AMD. It seems to work the first time that I restarted the computer, The computer was under 50°C, but at the second restart, startx refused to start. So I've reinstalled Xubuntu many times and tried to reinstall AMD, but I've got the same problem everytime (with catalyst 13.3 13.1 and 12). So, I would like to know if there is any other way to change the GPU, or reduce the heat.

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/190654/how-do-i-fix-an-overheating-problem...](http://askubuntu.com/questions/190654/how-do-i-fix-an-overheating-problem-with-an-hp-envy-4-ultrabook)

Comment: @nero Broken link.

Comment: @IanCarroll Sorry, grabbing the other link..

Comment: @IanCarroll Here you go... http://askubuntu.com/q/190654/101890

Comment: "31,3 GPU ops/seconds, 0,0 VFS ops/sec and 4,3% CPU use", for 70°C, I think it is a bit much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option to use PowerPlay in your ATI Catalyst Control Center, then you could change the plugged in state to "Maximize Battery Life".